# Why does Vulkan log configuration file errors on Instance creation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vulkan

I recently updated my code base's Vulkan SDK to 1.1.114.0 and encountered a strange error message when I create the Instance.

> E:[IU]   : Failed to open the configuration file! Exiting...

This message is printed to my Visual Studio 2019 Debug Console when I create an instance, enumerate physical devices, etc. (It's is worth noting that this error message does not seem to affect any of my code)

The vulkan-1.dll in my System32 folder is upto date, and the problem still persists even if I explicitly load the dll provided in the SDK folder

**Update**: Looking into the disassembly, the error prompt seems to be coming from a KernelBase.dll function, which vulkan-1.dll calls when creating an instance

Minimal code:

```
auto vulkan_dll = LoadLibraryA("vulkan-1.dll");

auto vkGetInstanceProcAddr = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>(::GetProcAddress(vulkan_dll, "vkGetInstanceProcAddr"));
auto vkCreateInstance = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkCreateInstance>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(nullptr, "vkCreateInstance"));

VkInstance instance = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
VkApplicationInfo instance_AI ={};
instance_AI.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
instance_AI.pNext              = nullptr;
instance_AI.pApplicationName   = "Testing";
instance_AI.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
instance_AI.pEngineName        = "Test Engine";
instance_AI.engineVersion      = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
instance_AI.apiVersion         = VK_VERSION_1_1;

VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_CI ={};
instance_CI.sType                   = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
instance_CI.pNext                   = nullptr;
instance_CI.flags                   = 0;
instance_CI.pApplicationInfo        = &instance_AI;
instance_CI.enabledLayerCount       = 0;
instance_CI.ppEnabledLayerNames     = nullptr;
instance_CI.enabledExtensionCount   = 0;
instance_CI.ppEnabledExtensionNames = nullptr;

auto instance_create_result = vkCreateInstance(&instance_CI, nullptr, &instance);
if (instance_create_result != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Failed to create an Instance!\n");
}
else
{
    auto vkDestroyInstance = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkDestroyInstance>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyInstance"));
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
}

FreeLibrary(vulkan_dll);
```

Comment: Check your environment variables for anything relating to validation layers.  You may have some old validation layer referenced or something.

Comment: @Jherico I checked, and I did have an old path entry, I removed it, restarted. The problem sill persists. I don't have any old installations of the SDK.

Comment: If you're on a windows environment, you should also check the registry entries that might be referring to validation layers under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\Vulkan`

Comment: That error message text does not appear in the source code repositories for the Vulkan Loader or Validation Layers.  Can you check your code base to make sure that there isn't something else emitting that message?  The "E:[IU]" prefix is also something I haven't seen in Vulkan components.  Did anything else change while doing the SDK upgrade?

Comment: @Jherico All the explicit layers refer to layers in 1.1.114.0 and the implicit layers are only Steam and RenderDoc.

Comment: @KarlSchultz I previously had an old installation of Vulkan installed in a different folder, but I uninstalled that and reinstalled 1.1.114.0

Comment: Probably the best thing to try next is to set the environment variable: VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all.  The output is a bit verbose, but it shows a lot about what the loader is doing and where it is looking for things like drivers and layers.  Hopefully, your error message will show up close enough to a loader diagnostic message that it suggests where it is coming from.

Comment: Does the message appear when you run the app outside of Visual Studio?  You might also want to collect some more data such as stack traces and output from the vkvia installation verification tool and submit it in an issue at https://vulkan.lunarg.com.

Comment: @KarlSchultz Here's part of the debug output: pastebin.com/yjkNaMmd line 60 is the error. Also the output only appears in the Visual Studio Debug Console, not the command line console.

Comment: My best guess is that the Vulkan Loader is loading the Intel Vulkan driver (igvk64.dll) and that driver is generating the message.  The Loader loads the driver so it can learn what capabilities and extensions it supports, even if you don't end up using it.  It is possible that the driver is looking for some sort of configuration file.  It might be helpful to reinstall the Intel drivers to see if that helps.  Or perhaps try to disable the Intel Vulkan driver to confirm that's where the message is coming from.

Comment: My other guess is that one of the explicit layers is emitting this message.  After the loader loads a driver, it calls that driver, but the explicit layers can hook these calls.  I've already ruled out RenderDoc because it does not contain strings for your error message.  Perhaps you can try temporarily disabling the Steam explicit layers by moving the layer json files out of the C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\ directory.

Comment: This error message originates from [Qt](http://qt.io).